# Displaying the function call stack in vim

Tags: c++, linux, vim

Is there a way to display in VIM/GVIM the call stack of a function while editing (not while running) the code?
I am using LINUX and C++. Suppose the example of code below

```
 void foo3(){}

 void foo2(){}

 void foo1(){
     foo2(){
         foo3(){
         }
     }    
 }
```

I am looking for a vim command or a plugin able to display a list below

```
foo1()
foo2()
foo3()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to have a look at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2368, its descent and serve the purpose for me.

Comment: It look like works for C only, am I right?P.S. thanks for the reply.

Comment: yes currently supported lang is C, do you also want for other lang?

Comment: For C++ i would suggest to give try to Eclipse with CDT

Comment: Sorry but I really would like to stick with VIM/GVIM.

Comment: Sure, but also have a look at http://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/features.html, i looked at it today and pretty nice!

Answer (score 1):

You could install [Eclim](http://eclim.org) which is a way to integrate Vim with Eclipse, your Vim instance is communicating to Eclipse instance via a daemon.

The display of call stack is supported. See [here](http://eclim.org/vim/c/inspection.html) for an example. You'll also get some other benefits from Eclipse like code completion and basic code validation.

From my personal experience, it is a bit cumbersome to use since you have to set up an Eclipse project, but this is a rather easy way to get IDE features into Vim, if this is your goal.